# Binding a key in C/C++ mode only?

Tags: emacs

I would like to bind my TAB key in emacs to clang-format-region when in C/C++ mode. How do I achieve this without affecting other modes? In particular, global-set-key doesn't achieve what I want, since it makes editing text with emacs a tad difficult.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `define-key` on c-mode-base-map (C, C++ ...)

```el
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "<tab>") 'clang-format-region)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use `local-set-key`

```
(add-hook
     'c++-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
      (local-set-key (kbd "<tab>") #'clang-format-region)))
```

Comment: Up-voting this because this is the only solution that worked for me. The local-set-key allows for overriding any global key maps inside the c++-mode. You are adding the key binding to the mode map.  [elisp-docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html#index-local_002dset_002dkey)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `define-key`:

```
(define-key c++-mode-map (kbd "<tab>") 'clang-format-region)
```